# Solving an infinite summation involving exponential and factorial

Tags: summation, exponential-function, factorial

I'm trying to understand an equality that I found in [this biology article](http://www.genetics.org/content/146/2/723.full.pdf).

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{e^{-x}x^i(1-y)^i}{i!} = e^{-x\cdot y}$$

Can you help me proving this equation holds true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factor $e^{-x}$ does not change as $i$ runs through the list  $0,1,2,3,\ldots$, so it can be pulled out, getting $$ e^{-x}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\cdots\cdots.$$

Then you have $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{a^i}{i!} = e^a $, where $a=x(1-y)$.

Comment: Why does $\sum \frac{a^i}{i!}=e^a$?

Comment: @Remi.b : Maybe you should make that a separate question.  In comments I'll say that it's a standard identity.  Try showing that if $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{c_k x^k}{k!}$ then $f^{(k)}(0)= c_k$, and figure out what $f^{(k)}(0)$ should be if $f(x) = e^x$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: ok, thank you. I asked this next question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666821/why-does-sum-i-0-infty-fracaii-ea)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [well known series expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) for $e^t$ for $t$ a real number.

Now $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(x(1-y))^i}{i!}=e^{x(1-y)}$. Since $e^{-x}$ factor doesn't  depend on $i$ we can pull it out. So we have that your = $e^{-x}e^{x-xy}$. Now use $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$ to get your conclusion.